# Why using clear text for Credit Card security code?

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card

I'm curious about the reason why <del>all</del> most payment gateway site use clear text input to take security code.

Isn't it more secure if users put their security code in password mode textbox?

please give me enlightenment on this

Comment: The same could be said for the credit card number and expiry date...

Comment: Having it said, do you think we should mask all of our credit card information? ;)

Comment: NO. Because unless your know the info, it is possible a user will make a mistake while entering it and they can't check before submitting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you used a password box for this, who exactly are you hiding the security code *from*? Presumably the user has their credit card out, in their hand, and somebody looking over their shoulder can just see the number on the card instead of the screen.

Jakob Nielsen recently made a case to [Stop Password Masking](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/passwords.html), that means for *all* password fields.
Bruce Schneier added his opinion in his article [The Pros and Cons of Password Masking](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/the_pros_and_co.html). If there's discussion about whether password masking is relevant for *password* fields, I wouldn't even consider using it for CCV fields.

The password prompt in your OS for the wireless password probably has an option to "show password".

Comment: I can remember my security code. it's only 3 digit I don't think would be hard to remember.

Comment: Ah, you young bucks with yer 20/20 eyesight.

Comment: I think Jakob Nielsen's Stop Password Masking is plain stupid (though I agree to getting rid of that Reset button). Apart from the obvious presentations and open work environments etcetera while actually in the process of logging in, I would also not like my browser to populate the password as plain visible text in many sites that I actually do not log in to (but which have a login box on every page).

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, the data is transmitted using HTTPS. Using a password field might even make the browser prompt whether to save the value for later use, and hence might not make it more secure. (But then, you're right, using a plain text field might make the browser remember it as well.) At least plain text is easier for the user.

Comment: +1 my browser always remember my number and security code. for me it's okay, I can delete the history. But if someone put his card information on shared computer and forgot to remove the data, everybody can use it.